# Sprite transparency fails when rendered through shader

Tags: unity, 2d, shaders, sprites, transparency

I am currently trying to implement a shader to a sprite of mine, but the transparency is completely removed when the texture goes through a Sample Texture 2D node.

The sprite under the Sample Texture 2D node.

[image]

The sprite Import settings

[image]

The sprite on a image viewer.

[image]

Comment: What do you see if you take the Alpha (A) pin and output it somewhere? That's the pin that carries the transparency information, and it might just not be shown in the RGB preview below.

Comment: I applied the A pin to a Negate node and it returned all black, meaning that no Alpha is being received on the shader? Though when using non-shader materials the transparency works fine. Something that I noticed is that the 'extra pixels' are just the outline pixels but stretched out to border of the image.

Comment: Try piping it to an "Add" node but add zero, rather than negating it. 1 negated is -1, which also shows up as black, so a negate node is a very bad choice for when you want to inspect data in the range 0 to 1. 

Comment: Ok, so, the alpha is actually returning properly, being white on colored pixels and black on empty ones. I tried fixing it through shader manipulation, making the A absolute, and combining with the rgb channels, but apparently it just goes back to the original texture.

Comment: Can you show us how you're connecting this to the master/output node in your graph? (Also, there's no need to use an absolute value node here, because again, RGBA32 data is in the range 0 to 1)

Comment: I found out what i was doing wrong. I was connecting the RGBA to the RGB output, but completely ignoring the Alpha one right below it. That was why the texture wasn't getting transparent. I can't believe how stupid I am.

Comment: You're not stupid, you're learning. Want to post your solution as an answer below, to help future readers learn how to do this too?

Answer (score 1):

I had forgotten to connect the Alpha Channel to the Output of the Shader.

[image]